# Redash how to change the dashboard datasource?

Tags: datasource, redash

I'm new to Redash and trying to use it to analyze data.

I have created several queries and added to a dashboard.

Is Redash possible to change the datasouce on dashboard level instead of changing the datasouce of query one by one? (all datasource with the same data structure, so query can share to use)

Answer (score 0):

Nope not yet. The queries underneath are tied to datasources, not the dashboard.

If you want to bulk update, you should be able to update the column in the `queries` table in postgres. The column `data_source_id` should allow you to do a bulk update.

Comment: I've tried to use the redash api for updating the datasource. Thanks